# How to auto fill a field in Google Forms based on dropdown list?

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-forms, gs-vlookup

I am trying to create a Google Form like this one with one drop-down list and two text fields(for now! If I get this down I would like to add drop downs instead of text fields).

Now I have manually added options in the drop down here.
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9VOr.png)

What I want is:

1. The drop down to dynamically pick values from a column called 'ID' in a Google Spreadsheet.
   [Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lm7w.png)
2. Auto-populate the corresponding values from Vertical and Project from the sheet to the text fields in the form.

How can I go about doing these?

Comment: A Google Form can not be dynamically changed when the user has it open for input.  You would need to design a Web App form and use that.